# Kotlin - What is the point of @PublishedApi?

Tags: kotlin

What is the difference between

```kotlin
@PublishedApi
internal class Foo
```

and

```
class Foo
```

According to the docs:

> the declaration becomes effectively public, and this should be considered with respect to binary compatibility maintaining.

So if it's "effectively public", what's the actual difference?

Comment: Very simple words: Internal classes can not be accessed from everywhere and thats exactly what you search. But then you recognize that you want to access this inner class and it's functions by some static/inline functions which are utils - so you can use this.
It's not making it public for all usages but granting it to some usecases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The IDE treats it as internal, but you can indirectly expose the code via inline functions.

The primary purpose is to allow public inline functions to call it without exposing it to being called directly from outside the module. In this sense, care has to be taken when modifying the function because it technically has been exposed in bytecode.